# Getting data from mutliple tables casuing duplicated data in view

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, controller, laravel-blade

i am trying to display data from two different tables

Controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $order = DB::table('order')->get();
    $order_item = DB::table('order_item')->get();
    return view('admin.orders', compact('order','order_item'));
}
```

View:

```
           @foreach ($order as $orders)
           @foreach ($order_item as $order_items)
           <tr>
            <th style="padding: 20px">{{ $orders->id }}</th>
            <th style="padding: 20px">{{ $order_items->order_id }}</th>

            <th style="padding: 20px">&nbsp;<a><i style="color: #6565D8"
                class="fa-solid fa-location-dot"></i></a>&nbsp;
            &nbsp;<a><i style="color: #6565D8" class="fa-solid fa-eye"></i></a>&nbsp;
            &nbsp;<a><i style="color: #6565D8" class="fa-solid fa-eye"></i></a>&nbsp;
            </th>
           </tr>
           @endforeach
           @endforeach
```

the problem in "$orders->id" it duplicate data to fulfill the same rows from the other table i am getting the same data (no duplicate) from "$order_items->order_id"

how to stop solve this issue?

[image]

Comment: Do you have Models? This looks like a many-to-many, `Order` and `Item`. (or possibly a one-to-many). You'd then do `$orders = Order::with('items')->get()`, then `@foreach($orders as $order)`, then `@foreach($order->items as $item)`. Right now, you're just looping over every record in both of the tables, so yes, you're going to have duplicated data. Please read the documentation, and get a better handle on relationships: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many. (or https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)

Answer (score 0):

You should make models for `Order` and `OrderItem` and then create proper relationships for each model.

For example, here's what your models could look like:

```php
// app/Models/Order.php
class Order extends Model 
{
    public function orderItems()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(OrderItem::class);
    }
}

// app/Models/OrderItem.php
class OrderItem extends Model 
{
    public function order()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Order::class);
    }
}
```

In your database, you would need an `order_id` column in your `order_items` table to connect them.

Then you can do what you want using eloquent like this:

```php
$orders = Order::withCount('orderItems')->get();

// do stuff with $orders, which now have `order_items_count` in the results.
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION:

so because i don't have model for the data i had to queries as showing below:

```
$orders = DB::table('order')
    ->select(['complaint.id','complaint.createdDate','complaint.user_id','complaint.createdDate','complaint.complaint_title','tbl_users.phone','tbl_users.email'])
    ->join('tbl_users', 'complaint.user_id', '=', 'tbl_users.id')
    ->get();
```